Driver on Windows with Python 3.12 returns DependencyException: "The C extension needed to use libev was not found"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DependencyException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 4
      1 # This should make a connection to a Cassandra instance your local machine 
      2 # (127.0.0.1)
----> 4 from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
      5 try:
      6     cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])

File c:\Users\12145\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\cassandra\cluster.py:173, in init cassandra.cluster()

DependencyException: Unable to load a default connection class
The following exceptions were observed: 
 - The C extension needed to use libev was not found.  This probably means that you didn't have the required build dependencies when installing the driver.  See http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/installation.html#c-extensions for instructions on installing build dependencies and building the C extension.
 - Unable to import asyncore module.  Note that this module has been removed in Python 3.12 so when using the driver with this version (or anything newer) you will need to use one of the other event loop implementations.

I have Python version on 3.12.3 and
Cassandra Python driver version 3.29.1 installed
I tried reinstalling the Cassandra drivers multiple times and also tried matching the version of the Cassandra drivers to the Python as well.

From the error you posted, it seems like the Cassandra Python driver was built without libev support. I am able to replicate the problem on a Windows 11 Pro laptop.
I've logged PYTHON-1386 to get it triaged and resolved.
In the meantime, you can workaround the issue by using WSL2 if that is acceptable to you. Cheers!
